# Xml insert fails in MySql .Warning 1265 Data truncated

Tags: mysql, xml, insert, truncate

An insert statement in Mysql inserts after truncating the XML(3200 characters).
I am trying to do an sql insert statement for this XML .
The Column desc is Varchar(21000).On insertion it gives a Warning 1265 Data truncated.
Strangely this works well on Oracle.

Comment: What language & data access provider are you using? can you provide the code that's causing the problem?

Comment: My Bad. This question was incorrectly asked.There was problem with the schema desc.